# Docker rootfs, the entrypoint script is indicating that it cannot find such a file or directory

Tags: docker

I am confident that the relevant executable files are present in the rootfs created by Docker, and that these files have executable permissions. However, the entrypoint script is indicating that it cannot find such a file or directory.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/static:nonroot

ARG TARGETARCH
WORKDIR /
USER 65532:65532

COPY bin/main-$TARGETARCH /manager

ENTRYPOINT ["/manager"]
```

This is my cmd of docker build:
`docker build -t myimage:tag .`

But when I docker run it by cmd `docker run myimage:tag .`

This error is:
`exec /manager: no such file or directory`

My docker version is that:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.0
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.4
 Git commit:        98fdcd7
 Built:             Mon May 15 18:49:22 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.0
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.4
  Git commit:       1331b8c
  Built:            Mon May 15 18:49:22 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061b
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

How to solve it? I ensure the manager exist in the rootfs

I want docker run success.

Comment: You can get this sort of error if the image is missing C library dependencies or if it names an interpreter that doesn't exist.  Where did the `/manager` originally come from?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  (Consider deleting the `docker version` output; it doesn't help reproduce the issue.)